# How to crash Bacula network backup system

Tags: 12.04

How do I crash a bacula network backup system .I was given a project to build a bacula network backup system and crash it ,then recover.I was able to build it but now im on crashing stage.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've been asked to test a backup system to make sure it does what it's intended to: Keep data safe. There are a few tests you can do to simulate this:

1. Assume one of your workstations was hit by a meteor and create a new one based off the backups.

   The process involves taking a computer, creating some documents, backing up and then reformatting and trying to recover. Document what you do to make recovery in the future a known process.
2. Assume a disk has died in the Bacula server. Can you recover? Can you keep writing backups? This usually requires a RAID6 solution.

   The quick way to test this is to just pull a disk from the array. If the whole system dies or at least ceases to be useful, you have a problem.
3. What happens if the Bacula server is hit by a meteor? Daily off-site copies of the last backup are essential but they need to be secure too. Tape or online.

The goal is that your office can be hit by a meteor and you can get the whole thing up and running in a new location within a day. If you can't do that, your backup system isn't working.