# How can I crash my MBR on ubuntu server

Tags: 12.04

How can I crash my MBR on ubuntu server.I am trying to crash my bacula system and when I was going through some documents I saw that I can do this by crashing the master boot record.Anybody to help

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "crash my MBR". Can you link to the documentation that told you to do this, so that others can understand what you mean?

Comment: Thank you very much for respondıng to my questıon.I was gıven a project to try bacula network backup system.I am suppose to ınstall and confıgure ıt ,the after that ım suppose to crash ıt so that ıt wont work or start ,Then on the conclusıon ım suppose to restore ıt to ıts fırst or normal state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in [your last iteration of this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342081/how-to-crash-bacula-network-backup-system), just test it with new hardware. Pretend that a meteor hit the old one and it doesn't exist. It's much safer than actually killing a working machine.

---

That said, you can wipe the MBR (replace sdx with the actual *disk* name):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=446 count=1
```

I shouldn't need to remind you that this is going to cause you real problems if you're doing it with a production machine that people need to work with.

---

In follow up to your comment, here's an extract from [Bacula's FAQ](http://www.bacula.org/5.2.x-manuals/en/problems/problems/Bacula_Frequently_Asked_Que.html):

> ### Does Bacula really save and restore all files?
>
> [How Can I Be Sure that Bacula Really Saves and Restores All Files? ] It is really quite simple, but took me a while to figure out how to "prove" it. First make a Bacula Rescue disk, see the Disaster Recovery Using BaculaRescueChapter chapter of this manual. Second, you run a full backup of all your files on all partitions. Third, you run an Verify InitCatalog Job on the same FileSet, which effectively makes a record of all the files on your system. Fourth, you run a Verify Catalog job and assure yourself that nothing has changed (well, between an InitCatalog and Catalog one doesn't expect anything). Then do the unthinkable, write zeros on your MBR (master boot record) wiping out your hard disk. Now, restore your whole system using your Bacula Rescue disk and the Full backup you made, and finally re-run the Verify Catalog job. You will see that with the exception of the directory modification and access dates and the files changed during the boot, your system is identical to what it was before you wiped your hard disk. Alternatively you could do the wiping and restoring to another computer of the same type.

Comment: Thank you very nuch.Im trying this on a separate machine .It ıs not used for production.ım only usıng ıt to test bacula.Lets say ı manage to crash ıt usıng that command you send me.Do you know how ı can restore ıt.

Comment: I've added an extract from their FAQ which appears to cover everything you're asking.